# How to change request method from POST to GET and extract from body request param using spring integration?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-webflux

I have a running api which expects prop as parameter. The task that I would like to solve is to create a proxy using spring integration which accepts post request with body. For example:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/proxy
    {
       "prop":"someval"
    }
```

then change request method to GET, extract prop value, set it as request param and send it to downstream api as

```
http://localhost:9999/greet/param?prop=someval
```

get response from the api and send it back to the client.

Here is what has been done:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow yourIntegrationFlow2() {
    return IntegrationFlow.from(WebFlux.inboundGateway("/proxy")
                    .requestMapping(mapping -> mapping.methods(HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST))
                    .requestPayloadType(Response.class)
            )
            .handle((GenericHandler<Response>) (payload, headers) -> {
                System.out.println(payload.getProp());
                return MessageBuilder.withPayload("").setHeader("queryParam",payload.getProp());
            })
            .handle(m->WebFlux.outboundGateway("http://localhost:9999/greet/param?{query}")
                    .uriVariable("query","prop="+m.getHeaders().get("queryParam"))
                    .httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET).charset("utf-8")
                    .mappedRequestHeaders("**")
                    .expectedResponseType(String.class))
            .get();
}

@Data
public class Response {
    private String prop;
}
```

The problem is when I send request to the proxy service using .http file, it is hanging

```
POST http://localhost:8080/proxy
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "prop": "val"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax `.handle(m->WebFlux` is wrong. You must not use a lambda variant, since you provide the whole handler via `WebFlux.outboundGateway()`.
Plus plain `handle(m ->)` is a lambda for `MessageHandler.handleMessage()` which returns `void` therefore no any reply produced as it is expected by the inbound gateway in the beginning of your flow.

The fix is just like this:

```
.handle(WebFlux.outboundGateway("http://localhost:9999/greet/param?{query}")
```